# Como parar o efeito de Escrever na tela com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Gente queria saber um meio de parar de escrever na tela quando chegasse no ultimo texto dentro de uma array, eu melhorei o código do [Simon Shahriveri](http://codepen.io/hi-im-si/pen/DHoup) veja agora o código reescrito em jQuery:

```js
'use strict';

var $self = $('#write');

var text = undefined ? binding.value.text : [$self.text()],
    delay = undefined ? binding.value.delay : 100,
    loopNum = 0,
    i = loopNum % text.length,
    fullTxt = text[i],
    isDeleting = false,
    txt = '',
    delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

function txtType() {

  if (isDeleting) {
    txt = fullTxt.substring(0, txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    txt = fullTxt.substring(0, txt.length + 1);
  }

  $self.text('').text(txt);

  if (isDeleting) delta /= 2;

  if (!isDeleting && txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = parseInt(delay, 10) || 2000;
    isDeleting = true;
  } else if (isDeleting && txt === '') {
    isDeleting = false;
    loopNum++;
    delta = delay;
  }

  setTimeout(function () {
    txtType();
  }, delta);
}

// Run
$(document).ready(function () {
  txtType();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="write">Please wait, loading...
  <p>
```

Ele foi adaptado para o `VueJS` como uma `directive` mas nesse momento o `binding.value` não esta em uso e eu queria como posso parar o efeito feito pelo loop do `setTimeout` dizendo que assim que escrever o último texto ele parar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que ele pare no último texto basta que adicione uma condição para não aplicar o `setTimeout`, para isso algumas alterações foram realizadas.

A primeira delas foi criar uma variável com nome `die`.

```
die = false;
```

Portanto precisamos saber se a próxima `array` (o próximo texto) existe, para isso foi utilizado:

```
if(typeof(text[loopNum + 1]) === 'undefined'){
      die = true;
}else{
      isDeleting = true;
}
```

Por fim foi adicionado o suporte para uma próxima frase utilizando:

```
 loopNum++;
 fullTxt = text[loopNum];
```

Para interromper o loop utilizamos:

```
if(die != true) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    txtType();
    console.log('x');
  }, delta);
}
```

Isso é suficente para que ele pare na última frase, mesmo se somente houver uma frase ou se houverem mais de uma.

```js
var $self = $('#write');

var text = undefined ? binding.value.text : [$self.text(), 'Isso é um teste', 'Essa é a última frase definida'],
  delay = undefined ? binding.value.delay : 100,
  loopNum = 0,
  i = loopNum % text.length,
  fullTxt = text[i],
  isDeleting = false,
  txt = '',
  delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100,
  die = false;

function txtType() {

  if (isDeleting) {
    txt = fullTxt.substring(0, txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    txt = fullTxt.substring(0, txt.length + 1);
  }

  $self.text('').text(txt);

  if (isDeleting) delta /= 2;

  if (!isDeleting && txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = parseInt(delay, 10) || 2000;

    if (typeof(text[loopNum + 1]) === 'undefined') {
      die = true;
    } else {
      isDeleting = true;
    }

  } else if (isDeleting && txt === '') {
    isDeleting = false;
    loopNum++;
    fullTxt = text[loopNum];
    delta = delay;
  }


  if (die != true) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      txtType();
      // Apenas para ver o Timeout:
      console.log('SetTimeOut');
    }, delta);
  }

}

// Run
$(document).ready(function() {
  txtType();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="write">Please wait, loading...
  <p>
```

> Adicionei o `console.log` para verificar que o loop irá ser interrompido após a última frase ser atingida. ;)

---

> Se somente houver um texto irá funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Mas no caso o `clearTimeout` vai sempre em execução e pode atrapalhar no desempenho? Tem algum jeito de dizer ao jQuery para de executar a function?

Comment: @iLeonardoCarvalho fiz a alteração para tornar mais "performatico", acrescentei um `console.log()` para verificar que realmente ele para de executar a loop. O JQuery não tem haver com o Timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se é exatamente isso que você deseja, mas vai uma possível solução:

```js
'use strict';

   
var text = $('#write').text(),
    arrayElements = ["Primeiro texto"," Segundo texto","Terceiro texto","Quarto texto"],
    delay = 100,
    loopNum = 0,
    arrayLimit = arrayElements.length,
    fullTxt = arrayElements[0],
    isDeleting = false,
    txt = '',
    delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

function txtType() 
{
  if (isDeleting)
      txt = fullTxt.substring(0, txt.length - 1);
  else
      txt = fullTxt.substring(0, txt.length + 1);

  $('#write').text('').text(txt);

  if (isDeleting)
      delta /= 2;

  if (!isDeleting && txt === fullTxt)
  {
      delta = parseInt(delay, 10) || 2000;
      isDeleting = true;
  }
  else
  if (isDeleting && txt === '')
  {
      isDeleting = false;
      loopNum++;
      if(loopNum >= arrayElements.length)
          return;
      delta = delay;
      fullTxt = arrayElements[loopNum];
  }

  setTimeout(function () 
  {
    txtType();
  }, delta);
}

// Run
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  txtType();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="write">Please wait, loading...<p>
```

Comment: bem isso só que no último texto ele ficasse visível do que ser apagado pelo `isDeleting`